# How can I manually modify models retrieved from the database in Django?

Tags: django

I wish to do something such as the following:

```
people = People.objects.filter(date=date)
person = people[0]
person['salary'] = 45000
```

The last line results in an error:

```
object does not support item assignment
```

To debug something like this I always find it easier to start with something working and modify line by line until something breaks.

I want to modify the object for rendering in the template.  If I try:

```
person.salary = 45000
```

There is no error but trying

```
print person.salary
```

Immediately afterwards results in the original value being printed. Update:

In my code I was actually doing:

```
people[0].salary = 45000
```

Which doesn't work.  For some reason

```
person = people[0]
person.salary = 45000
```

Does work.  I thought the two pieces of code would be exactly the same

Comment: That's odd... this is just a python object, and the setters are pretty straight forward. foo.bar = baz should not revert values w/o magic. **unless** you called `get()` or `filter()` again before saving.

Comment: agreed, you'll need to update your question a little bit.

Comment: Updated. Very strange.

Comment: That's a very important distinction. This is an issue that pops up here very often. Read below for a nice answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the IDs, it seems that when you assign an entry to a variable, you get its copy, not its original reference:

```
In [11]: people = People.objects.filter(salary=100)
In [12]: person = people[0]
In [13]: person.salary = 5000
In [14]: print person.salary
5000
In [15]: people[0].salary
Out[15]: 100
In [16]: id(people[0])
Out[16]: 35312400
In [17]: id(person)
Out[17]: 35313104
```

So, let's look at what it happens in depth. 
You know that in Django QuerySets are evaluated only when you need their results (lazy evaluation). To quote [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

> **Slicing**. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced,
>   using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet
>   usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute
>   the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax,
>   and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated
>   (partially or fully) also returns a list.

In particular, looking at the ['django.db.models.query' source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py),

```
    def __getitem__(self, k):
    """
    Retrieves an item or slice from the set of results.
    """
    # some stuff here ...

    if isinstance(k, slice):
        qs = self._clone()
        if k.start is not None:
            start = int(k.start)
        else:
            start = None
        if k.stop is not None:
            stop = int(k.stop)
        else:
            stop = None
        qs.query.set_limits(start, stop)
        return k.step and list(qs)[::k.step] or qs

    qs = self._clone()
    qs.query.set_limits(k, k + 1)
    return list(qs)[0]
```

you can see that when you use *slicing*, you are calling the `__getitem__` method. 
Then the `self._clone` method will provide you a different instance of the same QuerySet. This is the reason you are getting different results.

Answer (score 5):

`person` is an object, you need to do like this:

```
person.salary = 45000
person.save()
```

You should read [How to work with models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/).

Comment: I modified my question and read the documentation.  I still can't quite get Django to do what I want

Answer (score 0):

Object-relational mapping that Django models provide hides the fact that you are interacting with a DB, by providing object-oriented interface for retrieving and manipulating data.

Unfortunately, ORM abstraction is not perfect, there are various cases when ORM semantic does not match the intuition. In these cases you need to investigate what's going on on the underlying SQL layer to figure out the cause of troubles.

Your problem arises from the fact that:

```
people = People.objects.filter(date=date)
```

does not execute any SQL query.

```
people[0]
```

executes `SELECT a, b, c, .. FROM T WHERE filter`, if you modify the resulting object by calling:

```
people[0].salary = 45000
```

the modification won't be saved to the DB, because the `save()` method was not called. The next call to `people[0]` again executes a SQL query, which does not return the unsaved modification.

When you encounter problems like this, [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) can greatly help to identify which statements execute what SQL queries.